# Withdrawing profits from Huawei developers

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, huawei-account, huawei-iap

I am my application whose profits reached more than 300 euros and two months have passed since this profit, but I cannot withdraw it because there is no data in the Credited section[image]

As you can see, these are last month's earnings

[image]

[image]
As you can see there is nothing in the statistics to withdraw

Answer (score 1):

Pls follow [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/checkoutguide-0000001053128363?ha_source=hms1) for Self-service Settlement.

Huawei makes payments to merchants periodically based on confirmed settlement sheets. The settlement process is as follows:

1. Huawei provides settlement sheets for each settlement period (usually, a month) by the due date in each month, with detailed information about how your earnings are calculated. For example, Huawei will provide you with the settlement details for May on June 15.
2. You can check the provided settlement sheets and confirm them to submit a settlement application if all the settlement details are correct. For details, please refer to [Section 4.5 in the HUAWEI Developer Merchant Service Agreement](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/start/merchantserviceagreement-0000001052848245#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001052848245__section448382717416).
3. If invoicing is necessary, you can issue an invoice after confirming settlement sheets, and send it to Huawei by mail or email.
4. Huawei pays you according to the settlement application.

Comment: @shirkey   First of all, I am very happy for your interest in my question, but I want to clarify something
I started working since the 9th month, and so far I have made about 550 euros, approximately 300 euros per month. I waited for 1 Actor to view the settlement in my account, but nothing was sent to me
Today is November 1 and also there is nothing as you can see in the pictures
  I repeat. Thank you for the information. I am very happy that there are people like you who are interested in answering the last members.

Comment: hi@Mohammed Albirkawi, Could you please leave your appId? Let me check the info to see the problem.